# When scrolling right, div stops at left side of screen

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, position, sticky

I have a quick jQuery/css question. I am coding a site and have a grey box that will have content/links inside of it that I want to stick to the left side of the screen when the user scrolls right. I've gone through a bunch of forums/tutorials but still can't find my solution. Here is a link to the site.

I'm rather a novice when it comes to jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

http://morseandcompany.com/index-TEST.html

Comment: Well, you did set it to `position: fixed`, what did you think that would happen... Or did I not understand your question entirely..?

Comment: I'm trying to have the grey bar, which is going to have navigational links in it, stop and stick to the left side of the screen when people scroll to the right so that the navigation is always accessible. Much like this: satbulsara.com/tests but scrolling horizontally instead of vertically. Again, sorry for my lack of knowledge in this department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

This should be your document ready script:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var theLoc = $('#sidebar').position().left;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if(theLoc >= $(window).scrollLeft()) {
        if($('#sidebar').hasClass('fixed')) {
            $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    } else { 
        if(!$('#sidebar').hasClass('fixed')) {
            $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
        }
    }
});
});
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
.fixed {position:fixed !important; left:0px !important;}
```

And change the CSS for your #sidebar to:

```
#sidebar {
min-height:100%;
width:266px;
height:100%;
height: auto !important; /*for modern browsers */ 
background-color:#F2F2F2;
z-index:2;
}
```

And change the HTML for the sidebar to:

```
<DIV ID="sidebar" style="position:absolute; left:765px;"></DIV>
```

Comment: I'm trying to have the grey bar, which is going to have navigational links in it, stop and stick to the left side of the screen when people scroll to the right so that the navigation is always accessible. Much like this: http://satbulsara.com/tests/ but scrolling horizontally instead of vertically.


Again, sorry for my lack of knowledge in this department.

Comment: Don't gotta apologize, everyone's gotta learn. And thanks for that example. I've gotten it to work now. I'll edit my answer in a sec.

Comment: No problem. And if you want it to start moving along with the scroll sooner just change `if(theLoc >= $(window).scrollLeft() +20 ) {` and `.fixed {position:fixed !important; left:20px !important;}`  where 20px is the offset.

Answer (score 0):

When visiting your webpage, I get this error:

```
var docScrollRight = $('body,html').scrollRight();
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That isn't a jQuery function. Try `scrollLeft()`.

Comment: lol, it would make sense that it existed but sadly, it doesn't.